# Unfortunately app has stopped in android emulator

Tags: android

My app has no issue in opening the first screen in the emulator.But when i click the button of first page to enter the nect page-screen2,i get an error "unfortunately myapp has stopped".Kindly help me

this is screen1.java

```
package com.example.library;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
public class Screen1 extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_screen1);
        Button login=(Button)findViewById(R.id.loginBtn);

        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent screen1i= new Intent(Screen1.this, Screen2.class);           
                startActivity(screen1i);
                        }
                    });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.screen1, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Screen2.java

```
package com.example.library;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Screen2 extends Activity {



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_screen2);



    Button orderButton1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.mpBtn);

    orderButton1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

Intent intent1= new Intent(Screen2.this, Screen3.class);            
startActivity(intent1);
        }
    });
}

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.screen2, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.

        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
    return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

android manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.library"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="17"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".Screen1"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Screen2"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_screen2"
            android:parentActivityName=".Screen1" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.example.
                library.Screen1" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Screen3"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_screen3"
            android:parentActivityName=".Screen2" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.example.library.Screen2" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Second"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_second" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Screen4"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_screen4"
            android:parentActivityName=".Screen3" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.example.library.Screen3" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Screen5"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_screen5"
            android:parentActivityName=".Screen4"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.example.library.Screen4" />
        </activity>


    </application>

</manifest>
```

logcat

```
02-22 13:45:31.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1115): Process: com.example.library, PID: 1115
02-22 13:45:31.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1115): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.library/com.example.library.Screen2}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19: Error inflating class textview
02-22 13:45:31.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1115):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
02-22 13:45:31.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1115):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
02-22 13:45:31.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1115):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
02-22 13:45:31.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1115):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
02-22 13:45:31.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1115):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
02-22 13:45:31.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1115):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
02-22 13:45:31.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1115):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
02-22 13:45:31.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1115):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-22 13:45:31.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1115):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-22 13:45:31.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1115):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
02-22 13:45:31.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1115):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
02-22 13:45:31.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1115):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-22 13:45:31.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1115): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19: Error inflating class textview
02-22 13:45:31.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1115):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:707)
02-22 13:45:31.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1115):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
02-22 13:45:31.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1115):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
02-22 13:45:31.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1115):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
02-22 13:45:31.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1115):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
02-22 13:45:31.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1115):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
02-22 13:45:31.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1115):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
02-22 13:45:31.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1115):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)
02-22 13:45:31.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1115):     at com.example.library.Screen2.onCreate(Screen2.java:22)
02-22 13:45:31.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1115):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
02-22 13:45:31.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1115):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
02-22 13:45:31.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1115):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
02-22 13:45:31.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1115):     ... 11 more
02-22 13:45:31.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1115): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.textview" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.library-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.library-2, /system/lib]]
02-22 13:45:31.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1115):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
02-22 13:45:31.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1115):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
02-22 13:45:31.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1115):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
02-22 13:45:31.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1115):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:559)
02-22 13:45:31.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1115):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:652)
02-22 13:45:31.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1115):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)
02-22 13:45:31.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1115):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
02-22 13:45:31.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1115):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
02-22 13:45:31.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1115):     ... 22 more
02-22 13:45:31.891: W/ActivityManager(387):   Force finishing activity com.example.library/.Screen2
02-22 13:45:32.001: W/ActivityManager(387):   Force finishing activity com.example.library/.Screen1
02-22 13:45:32.791: W/ActivityManager(387): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{b30ff8b0 u0 com.example.library/.Screen2 t3 f}
02-22 13:45:33.011: I/Choreographer(387): Skipped 30 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-22 13:45:33.771: I/Choreographer(1036): Skipped 46 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-22 13:45:34.181: W/EGL_emulation(1036): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
02-22 13:45:35.291: D/AlertService(946): No fired or scheduled alerts
02-22 13:45:35.351: D/AlertService(946): Scheduling next alarm with AlarmScheduler. sEventReminderReceived: null
02-22 13:45:35.411: D/AlarmScheduler(946): No events found starting within 1 week.
02-22 13:45:35.421: I/ActivityManager(387): Resuming delayed broadcast
02-22 13:45:36.061: I/ActivityManager(387): Delay finish: com.android.providers.calendar/.CalendarProviderBroadcastReceiver
02-22 13:45:36.501: I/ActivityManager(387): Resuming delayed broadcast
02-22 13:45:36.661: I/ActivityManager(387): Delay finish: com.android.mms/.transaction.SmsReceiver
02-22 13:45:36.731: V/SmsReceiverService(919): onStart: #1 mResultCode: -1 = Activity.RESULT_OK
02-22 13:45:37.081: E/SoundPool(387): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
02-22 13:45:37.081: W/AudioService(387): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
02-22 13:45:37.101: E/SoundPool(387): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
02-22 13:45:37.101: W/AudioService(387): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
02-22 13:45:37.121: E/SoundPool(387): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
02-22 13:45:37.121: W/AudioService(387): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
02-22 13:45:37.161: E/SoundPool(387): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
02-22 13:45:37.161: W/AudioService(387): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
02-22 13:45:37.471: D/dalvikvm(387): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 618K, 18% free 6322K/7676K, paused 259ms, total 267ms
02-22 13:45:37.471: E/SoundPool(387): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
02-22 13:45:37.481: W/AudioService(387): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
02-22 13:45:37.481: E/SoundPool(387): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
02-22 13:45:37.481: W/AudioService(387): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
02-22 13:45:37.481: E/SoundPool(387): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
02-22 13:45:37.501: W/AudioService(387): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
02-22 13:45:37.501: E/SoundPool(387): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
02-22 13:45:37.501: W/AudioService(387): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
02-22 13:45:37.501: E/SoundPool(387): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
02-22 13:45:37.501: W/AudioService(387): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
02-22 13:45:37.521: I/Process(1115): Sending signal. PID: 1115 SIG: 9
02-22 13:45:37.661: E/SoundPool(387): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressInvalid.ogg
02-22 13:45:37.661: W/AudioService(387): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressInvalid.ogg
02-22 13:45:37.671: W/AudioService(387): onLoadSoundEffects(), Error -1 while loading samples
02-22 13:45:37.881: I/Choreographer(387): Skipped 48 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-22 13:45:38.941: I/ActivityManager(387): Process com.example.library (pid 1115) has died.
02-22 13:45:38.971: I/WindowState(387): WIN DEATH: Window{b3003ac0 u0 com.example.library/com.example.library.Screen1}
02-22 13:45:39.551: D/dalvikvm(919): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 340K, 13% free 2872K/3284K, paused 97ms, total 118ms
02-22 13:45:39.601: E/StrictMode(919): A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.
02-22 13:45:39.601: E/StrictMode(919): java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'release' not called
02-22 13:45:39.601: E/StrictMode(919):  at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.open(CloseGuard.java:184)
02-22 13:45:39.601: E/StrictMode(919):  at android.drm.DrmManagerClient.<init>(DrmManagerClient.java:258)
02-22 13:45:39.601: E/StrictMode(919):  at com.google.android.mms.pdu.PduPersister.<init>(PduPersister.java:288)
02-22 13:45:39.601: E/StrictMode(919):  at com.google.android.mms.pdu.PduPersister.getPduPersister(PduPersister.java:296)
02-22 13:45:39.601: E/StrictMode(919):  at com.android.mms.transaction.TransactionService.onNewIntent(TransactionService.java:224)
02-22 13:45:39.601: E/StrictMode(919):  at com.android.mms.transaction.TransactionService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(TransactionService.java:621)
02-22 13:45:39.601: E/StrictMode(919):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
02-22 13:45:39.601: E/StrictMode(919):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
02-22 13:45:39.601: E/StrictMode(919):  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
02-22 13:45:39.831: I/ActivityManager(387): Resuming delayed broadcast
02-22 13:45:40.041: I/ActivityManager(387): Delay finish: com.android.providers.calendar/.CalendarProviderBroadcastReceiver
02-22 13:45:40.151: I/ActivityManager(387): Resuming delayed broadcast
02-22 13:45:40.231: V/AlarmClock(967): AlarmInitReceiver android.intent.action.TIME_SET
02-22 13:45:41.161: I/AlarmClock(967): Displaying next alarm time: ''
02-22 13:45:41.291: V/AlarmClock(967): AlarmInitReceiver finished
02-22 13:45:41.751: I/MediaFocusControl(387):  AudioFocus  abandonAudioFocus() from android.media.AudioManager@b2d25998com.android.music.MediaPlaybackService$3@b2d24818
02-22 13:47:37.971: D/dalvikvm(515): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 530K, 16% free 3300K/3900K, paused 227ms, total 238ms
```

Comment: Show LogCat errors...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19: Error inflating class textview
>
> ...
>
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.textview"

You have an erroneous reference to "textview" as an element at line 19 of your layout XML, presumably the one for Screen2.

To work it needs to have the correct capitalization, ie, "TextView"